# No font on axes in Plot3D graphics

Tags: plotting, fonts, linux, raspberry-pi

I am running Mathematica on Linux (Raspbian to be exact), and it seems I am missing some Mathematica fonts:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The problem is with the default color depth of the Raspberry pi, see [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/837538)

Comment: Ah, I was wondering whether this was the right board. Thank you sir.

Comment: Very interesting feature, it looks like MMA knowns how approximately minus and dot look like (they do not occupy the whole vertical space), but just want to conceal the symbols...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to save visitors from having to click through to other sites, the issue here is that the default color depth for Raspbian (the Raspberry Pi flavor of Linux) is 16 bit, and Mathematica expects 24 bit or higher.  In `/boot/config.txt` add the lines

```
# To make 3D plots in Mathematica look nicer
framebuffer_depth=32
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
```

The last line does not appear to be absolutely necessary; I cannot easily notice a difference in performance.

For reference, the original issue was identified on the [WC site](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/837538) and details for changing the color depth are found in a variety of places [such as here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=81132).  The question about performance was mentioned in the [github issue tracking](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/41) back a few years, and may no longer be relevant. (At least, it isn't on my v2 or v3 units.)